# How to differentiate between vertical and horizontal splitting of a view

Tags: layout, api

I'm working on the programming interface (public functions) to an API for graphical UI layout. The API does everything in terms of frame objects - simple rectangles in which stuff can be displayed.

I have methods to split these frames in half, either vertically or horizontally, but I'm having trouble coming up with an obvious name for the methods. `SplitVertical`, for example, could mean either:

1. split with a vertical line, leaving one half to each side
2. split into two halves which are arranged vertically (one above the other)

Is there a good way to resolve this ambiguity? Perhaps a more meaningful term?

**Note:** (to clear up some of the confusion) I am talking about the user interface that exists between the API programmer (myself) and the API end user (an application programmer), *not* the interface that the application programmers will create for *their* end users:

[image]

Comment: This seems like programming question, not a UI one.

Comment: Yes, programming questions are off-topic for this site. Although this question would be on topic if you were asking about button labels rather than method names. (Not quite the same thing, but close enough that you may get useful answers.) I hope you don't mind, @e.James, **I rephrased your question** to make it about UI.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney: I don't mind at all, but I'm surprised that all programming questions are automatically off-topic, especially considering that an API *is* a user interface. It just happens to be an interface whose users are also programmers.

Comment: @Patrick - a user interface doesn't have to be graphical.

Comment: @ChrisF, @e.James Thanks for your feedback. We're still in beta and still trying to figure some of these things out. I guess questions about *designing* APIs should be considered on topic. I rolled back the change.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney: It is definitely a tricky issue. I wasn't sure whether to post this on SO or here. I would almost say that we need a stackexchange cross-posting solution for questions that can legitimately exist on two different sites simultaneously.

Comment: @Parick I agree that a UI doesn't have to be graphical, but this is a *programming* interface question, not an end *user* interface question.  Big difference.  IMHO, it definitely does not belong here.

Comment: @Hisham: I disagree. The public interface to an API is a user interface in which the end user *is* another programmer. Why should being a programmer disqualify someone as a valid end user? Take for example the Windows API or Apple's Cocoa framework. I'm sure those companies spent a lot of time working out how their application developers would interact with those tools. The API or library is the tool, the app developers are the end user, and the public interface to the API is the user interface that the app developers use.

Comment: If we were to follow this logic (that the end user is another programmer), then why not have statisticians post questions on ANOVAs as well?  After all, the end user *is* another statistician.  We can welcome them here instead of on http://stats.stackexchange.com.  Discussion of APIs (Application *Programming* Interface) does not belong here.  It is irrelevant not only to 99.9% of end users, but also to UI and user experience practitioners.

Comment: @Hisham: Is it possible for a statistician to develop a *new* ANOVA tool, and in doing so, create a new way for other statisticians to use it? I would be tempted to call that a user interface, but I don't know enough about stats to make the call. Obviously, the inner workings of such a tool would be off-topic here.

Comment: @Hisham: Our disagreement seems to stem from the definition of "end user". You say that API design is irrelevant to 99.9% of end users and also to UI and user experience practitioners, but that "statistic" obviously depends on your definition of "end user". I think (as I have said earlier) that the users of an API are its end users. As such, I think that UI and user experience practitioners *should* be interested in such things. In no way am I proposing that we discuss the programming itself.

Comment: @e.James I agreed with @Patrick earlier that "a UI doesn't have to be graphical".  However, I does have to be something that the **end user can see and interact with**, whether it's graphical, text-based, using dials and sliders, braille, or even an abacus. However, *how* the UI is implemented becomes a backend, not front end issue, and as such it is completely irrelevant IMO to most end users, and even UI practitioners on this forum.  I don't see how discussing an application *programming* interface can be anything but a backend issue.

Comment: @Hisham: I understand what you are saying, but you insist that an application programmer who is making use of an API does not qualify as an end user of that API, and I that is what I disagree with. I'm not even talking about the end users for the application itself. The back end here is the guts of the API, the front end is the public functions and variables exposed by that API, and the end user is the application programmer.

Comment: @e.James I do agree with you that the application programmer is also the end user.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear when I gave the example of a statistician earlier.  But that in itself isn't sufficient.  An API question is not a UI question.  They are not even related.  An engine designer is also a car driver, but it wouldn't be appropriate of her to post a question about the minutiae of spark plug design on a popular car driving forum just because she happens to also drive a car.

Comment: @Hisham: I posted an image in the question to illustrate what I am talking about. I feel like we are both arguing passionately about different things, which is why we haven't been able to find any common ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how well they fit the rest of your API,  but how about these:

- Instead of `SplitVertical()`, how about `DivideIntoColumns()`
- Instead of `SplitHorizontal()`, how about `DivideIntoRows()`

Comment: I like those. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

If the application allows you, you could use icons with labels besides them. something like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/432554/ggf.png

or you could create a menu like:  **Split View:**  Horizontally   |   Vertically

But if you ask me, there's no ambiguity with using Split Vertical and Split Horizontal

Comment: +1 and thank you for the answer. I should have been more clear: I'm writing a *programming* API, so there are no icons or menus, it is basically a set of public functions that offer access to more advanced behavior. You could be right about the lack of ambiguity, though. Maybe it's just me!